# When trying to access the "pricePerUnit" in the hypixel api, i get the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pricePerUnit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, discord.js

`{"success":true,"lastUpdated":1598982272495,"products":{"BROWN_MUSHROOM":{"product_id":"BROWN_MUSHROOM","sell_summary":[{"amount":160,"pricePerUnit":13.9,"orders":1},{"amount":28503,"pricePerUnit":13.8,"orders":2},{"amount":71483,"pricePerUnit":13.4,"orders":3},`
this is what the api says so i assumed that i could directly get the "pricePerUnit. But I am getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pricePerUnit' of undefined`

My code is: ```client.on("message", message => {
if (message.author.bot) return;

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === "bazaar") {
    let product = args[0];

    fetch(`https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar/product?key=${key}`)
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(({ BROWN_MUSHROOM }) => {
        // Log the player's username
        message.reply(BROWN_MUSHROOM.pricePerUnit)
    })

}
```

})```

anybody know how to help?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your last block to this:

```
.then(({ products: { BROWN_MUSHROOM } }) => {
    // Log the player's username
    message.reply(BROWN_MUSHROOM.pricePerUnit)
})
```

since `BROWN_MUSHROOM` appears to be under `products` field.